# Can I use an Elecom game controller with Batman: Arkham City?

Tags: controllers, batman-arkham-city

I am playing *Batman: Arkham City* on a Windows 7 PC, purchased using Steam. The keyboard controls seemed less than ideal so I thought I'd bite the bullet and get a USB game controller.

At the store, they looked to be all the same, in that there was no indication that one brand or another would only work with certain games or anything like that. They all promoted plug and play capability and Windows 7 support.

I selected an Elecom wireless game controller, because wireless seems like a nice idea.

However, now that I'm in front of my computer, and I've installed the drivers for the controller from the supplied CD, *Batman: Arkham City* seems not to acknowledge it.

I now realize that the controls section in the game settings look fairly specific to a an Xbox controller.

So... did I just waste thirty bucks? Or can I get *Batman: Arkham City* to work with my new game controller?

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be an issue with non-Xbox 360 controller support for Arkham City. I've seen some people having success with the [Xbox 360 Controller Emulator](http://code.google.com/p/x360ce/downloads/list), so you might want to give that a try and see if it works.

Some people have also had luck with just modifying their config files, but the setting seem to be specific to each controller interface, so I'm not sure what it would be for yours. If you want to play around with it, it should be under Documents/WB Games/Batman Arkham City/BmGame/BmInput.ini or DefaultInput.ini. I can't recommend anything specific, but others indicated the following change worked for their controllers:

> In the folder BMGame>Config>DefaultInput.ini­, goto this line:
>
> > .Bindings=(Name="XboxTypeS_Lef­tY",Command="Axis aBaseY Speed=1.0
> >       DeadZone=0.3 | Axis aRawLHJoyUp Speed=1.0 DeadZone=0.0" )...
>
> Change both '1.0' to '-1.0'...
>
> Then goto the next 2 lines, & swap the words "up" and "right" in both
>   lines...

This was recommended by a user on [this Youtube guide](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QqNz4qjDvaY)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the software called [xinput](http://code.google.com/p/xinput/downloads/detail?name=xbox360cemu.v.3.0.rar&can=2&q=). Luckily this game is xinput compatible.

Unrar the files there, put files in main game directory, and run xinputtest. If the controls are messed up, change in the configuration settings. Play the game with the controller and don't forget to enjoy.

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion. It seems promising. However, I placed the files in the game directory (under the "Binaries" directory), and when I run `XInput Test`, I get what looks like perfect response on all buttons on the controller. However, when I start the game, it still seems like the game does not acknowledge the controller. Is there any other steps besides putting the files in the game directory?